# Eclipse Java AST parser: insert statement before if/for/while

Tags: java, eclipse, parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm using the org.eclipse.jdt parser.

I want to rewrite this code:

```
public void foo(){
...
...
if(a>b)
...
...
}
```

into this:

```
public void foo(){
...
...
System.out.println("hello");
if(a>b)
...
...
}
```

Supposing that ifnode is an IF_STATEMENT node, I can do something similar to this:

```
Block block = ast.newBlock();
TextElement siso = ast.newTextElement();
siso.setText("System.out.println(\"hello\");");

ListRewrite listRewrite = rewriter.getListRewrite(block, Block.STATEMENTS_PROPERTY);    
listRewrite.insertFirst(ifnode, null);
listRewrite.insertFirst(siso, null);

rewriter.replace(ifnode, block, null);
```

but this will insert the syso statement at the beginning of the method, while I want it right before the if.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the below code to achieve this (this will add the sysout just before the first `IfStatement`) :

```
Block block = ast.newBlock();
TextElement siso = ast.newTextElement();
siso.setText("System.out.println(\"hello\");");

ListRewrite listRewrite = rewriter.getListRewrite(block,  CompilationUnit.IF_STATEMENT);    
listRewrite.insertFirst(siso, null);

TextEdit edits = rewriter.rewriteAST(document, null);
```

Also you can limit the scope of rewrite to the `IfStatement`:

```
ASTRewrite rewriter = ASTRewrite.create(ifNode.getAST());
```

Note: code not tested. Do let me know if you find any issues.

Comment: ListRewrite listRewrite = rewriter.getListRewrite(block,  CompilationUnit.IF_STATEMENT); is not a valid statement since getListRewrite() needs a second parameter which is of type ChildListPropertyDescriptor whereas CompilationUnit.IF_STATEMENT returns int.