# how to build a for statement in AST using java parser?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree

I am using java parser and I want to build a `for` statement in a certain method such as the main method.
I could write a statement that prints on screen

```
(System.out.println("hello world")
```

but I could not build a `for` statement.

Comment: [Possible Answer to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111704/eclipse-java-ast-parser-insert-statement-before-if-for-while)

Comment: Can you please tell me you managed to write System.out.println?

Answer (score 2):

i'm using project com.github.javaparser :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // creates an input stream for the file to be parsed
    FileInputStream in;
    try {
        in = new FileInputStream("test.java");
        try {
            // parse the file
            CompilationUnit cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
            new MyMethodVisitor().visit(cu, null);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            in.close();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

//Method visitor

```
 private static class MyMethodVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter {

    @Override
    public void visit(MethodDeclaration method, Object arg) {
        //
        System.out.println("method body : " + method.toString());
        System.out.println("*******************************");
        //
        addForStmt(method.getBody());
        //
        System.out.println("method body : " + method.toString());
        //
    }

    private void addForStmt(BlockStmt body) {

        int beginLine = body.getBeginLine();
        int beginColumn = body.getBeginColumn();
        int endLine = body.getEndLine();
        int endColumn = body.getEndColumn();
        //
        List<Expression> init = new ArrayList<Expression>();
        Expression compare = null;
        List<Expression> update = null;
        BlockStmt methodBody = new BlockStmt();
        ForStmt forStmt = new ForStmt(beginLine, beginColumn, endLine, endColumn, init, compare, update, methodBody);
        //
        ASTHelper.addStmt(body, forStmt);
    }

}
```

**output:**

[Before]

```
method body : public void forStatementMethod() {}
```

[After]

```
method body : public void forStatementMethod() {
for (; ; ) {
}
}
```

//test.java

```
public class test<E> {

public void forStatementMethod() {
}
}
```

Sample Project in [github:issamux](https://github.com/issamux/JavaParserSample.git)